# Does my son need a visa to travel in and out of Italy while on a study abroad trip?

Tags: visas, schengen, us-citizens

My son is joing a study abroad program in Florence Italy through Washington State University February-April 2015.  He'd like to get a eur-rail pass to travel in and out of Italy during his 89-day program stay.  Does he need a Visa to get in and out of Italy while there?

Comment: What nationality does your son have (i.e., what country is written on his passport)? Note that the "Washington State University" hint does not provide this information as they surely have international students.

Comment: ...also, which countries does your son want to visit - only ones in the Schengen Area (see Wikipedia for a definition) but also others?

Comment: He is a US Citizen (sorry to have omitted that).  I believe he plans to travel to countries within the Schengen Area - France, Germany for short visits while there.  Just don't want him to get stuck somewhere and not be able to get back to school in Florence.

Comment: @Annamarie What kind of visa is he getting to study?

Comment: The program doesn't require a visa at all because the duration is 89 days.  Just wondering if he needs one to get in and out of Italy to tour other countries while he's there.

Comment: @Annamarie: There are no border controls when traveling between Italy and other Schengen countries.

Comment: ...however, random checks for ID by the police on trains that cross borders are not uncommon.

Answer (score 2):

United States nationals can enter the Schengen Area for stays of up to 90 days and travel freely within the area, as long as their *total* time spent in *all* Schengen countries does not exceed 90 days in any 180-day period.

So your son will not need a visa at all.

If he *leaves* the Schengen Area (such as to go to the United Kingdom) whether he needs a visa will depend on the rules of the country he's going to, of course. However, there should not be any trouble getting *back* into the Schengen area -- on the contrary, the 90-day limit will be extended by the number of days he spends outside Schengen. Be sure to get appropriate exit and entry stamps when crossing the external borders.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response - that simplifies things tremendously.

Comment: A slight addition: the Schengen rules is that 90 days of presence is allowed within *any* 180 days period. So  short-term stays outside the area does not add to the 90 days in this case. However, the (full) days spent outside of the Schengen area would not be counted towards the 90 days. Probably this is what is meant in the answer.

Comment: @DCTLib: Yes, that's what I'm referring to.